# Googlescript attaching a PDF to Email. Getting Server error

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

My mail script is working perfectly fine but when I try and attach a PDF the whole world comes crashing down.  I have been getting the error  "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again".

I have also tried various iterations of the attachment function and each has failed. Including blob, file ,get mine and the likes (by this time I have turned into a human blob myself lol) .

Please have  a look at the function. I sincerely hope someone can help with this.  The problematic part is in the last 5 lines of the code (the attachment function).

I must point out though that various members from our community have helped me in building this up. Thank you in anticipation

```
function welcome(){
var hour = new Date().getHours();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
var length = sheets.length;
for( var i=0; i < length; i++) {
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[i];
  var sheetName = sheet.getName()
  const emailAddress = "marketing@theperch.in";
  const subject = "Bookingmail Script not executed"
  const message = "Please check script and run again"
  if(sheetName != "name of sheet to be excluded"){

    bookingmail(sheet)
    }}
  }


 function bookingmail(sheet) {

 var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()
var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn() //  Number of rows and coloumns to 
process 


var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT"; // This constant is written in column V for 
rows for which an email
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, lastCol) // Fetch 
values for each row in the Range
var message = sheet.getRange("W2").getValue(); // This is for cell W2
var data = dataRange.getValues();

// Loop created to fulfill the if conditions and then execute mailsend app
for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
var row = data[i];
var emailAddress = row[8];  // Ninth column
 var emailSent = row[21]; // Twenty second column
var daysleft = row[20]; // Twenty first coloumn
var subject = "Your upcoming stay; Helpful Information "; // E-Mail Subject
var file = DriveApp.getFileById('0B3R47ecEHS2-WUFRTmFaT2piWDg');

//I have added a condition to make sure that it will only send if the 
customer has not already received an email
if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT && emailAddress != '' && (daysleft === 0 || 
daysleft === 1)) { // Prevents sending sending same mail again to a person, 
also 
skips blank cells
                                                                     //if 
daysleft =1 or 0 then send mail .
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF), blob],
name: 'Welcome mail- Perch Arbor Golf Course.pdf'});
 sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 22).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
// Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is 
interrupted
}
}
   SpreadsheetApp.flush();//you only need to do this when all the rows have 
been processed
}
```

Comment: It seems that for ``attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF), blob],``, ``blob`` is not defined. Is this unrelated to the error?

Comment: Yes, the problem is with the blob.  attachment function. I am not sure how to fix this. Can you please provide me a work-around. I got the same error when I tried the following function as well                           
                                                                                                
  attachments: [file],
    name: 'Welcome mail- Perch Arbor Golf Course.pdf'})

Comment: ``file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)`` works fine. This is a blob. But if ``0B3R47ecEHS2-WUFRTmFaT2piWDg`` is not Google Docs, this is possible to occur errors. Can I ask you about the file type of ``0B3R47ecEHS2-WUFRTmFaT2piWDg``?

Comment: It is a PDF file which is in my google drive

Comment: OK. Please modify from ``attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF), blob],`` to ``attachments: [file.getBlob()],`` and try to run again. Also ``file.getBlob()`` converts automatically Google Docs to PDF.

Comment: Hi , no luck still. Got the same error "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again"                                                                             This is what I changed the script to.                                                                                                                                                       MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
   attachments: [file.getBlob()],                                                                         
    name: 'Welcome mail- Perch Arbor Golf Course.pdf'});

Comment: @ Tanaike - Any luck?

Comment: Can I ask you about the file? Is the file yours? If the file is not your file, the error may occur. And/or can you try to send an e-mail using a simple script? Pattern 1. ``MailApp.sendEmail("## your e-mail##", "subject", "message");``, Pattern 2. ``MailApp.sendEmail("## your e-mail##", "subject", "message", {attachments: [DriveApp.getFileById("## file ID ##").getBlob()]});``. If these patterns work fine, it is considered that there is the problem for other position. I'm sorry for taking your time.

Comment: It works fine without the attachment. As soon as I add this line    it gives an error  "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again      "                                                                                                                                                                                           
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {attachments: [DriveApp.getFileById("0B3R47ecEHS2-eVpEWXBkLTB6MGc").getBlob()]});

Comment: dont know what to do :(

Comment: Can I ask you about my question of my latest comment? "If the file is not your file, the error may occur. And/or can you try to send an e-mail using a simple script?" And for example, how about the other file as an attachment file? I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Hey, I managed to get it running. I re-wrote it and it worked. The file was mile only and in my google Drive. I think the issue comes if you do no have an exit loop.

Comment: Thank you for your additional information.